# Positioning certain number of divs from left to right and then again from left to right in lower part

Tags: html, css

I have certain number of dynamically generated #divs with known .className(All have same className) but unknown Id's. I want to make the size (width , height) of the #divs to be fixed and then to show them from left to right, in one row and then to next row if it does not fit in the row. I tried (float : left ) , But the element below the last div, also displays on the left and gives an ugly look + the divs are not in same size(they have variable length of text). What is the css properties and how to set it to do the magic for me....

I am not quiet sure but i think the problem should be solved by some form of positioning (absolute , relative, etc) be defined for the classes.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrapperDiv{
                overflow:auto;
                background-color:green;
                position:relative;
            }

            .column{
                background-color:aqua;
                width:20em;
                height:20em;
                float:left;
                margin:2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <div class="wrapperDiv">
            <table class="column">
                                    <tr><td>Name<hr/></td></tr><tr><td>DataType :</td><td><select name="Name_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" ><option value="text" selected="true" > Text </option><option value="number"  > Number </option><option value="date"  > Date </option></select></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Equals:</td><td> <input type="text" name="Name_equals"/></td></tr> <br/><tr><td>Contains:</td><td> <input type="text" name="Name_contains"/></td></tr><br/>
                                    </table> 

            <table class="column">
                                    <tr><td>Name<hr/></td></tr><tr><td>DataType :</td><td><select name="Name_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" ><option value="text" selected="true" > Text </option><option value="number"  > Number </option><option value="date"  > Date </option></select></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Equals:</td><td> <input type="text" name="Name_equals"/></td></tr> <br/><tr><td>Contains:</td><td> <input type="text" name="Name_contains"/></td></tr><br/>
                                    </table> 

            <table class="column">
                                    <tr><td>Name<hr/></td></tr><tr><td>DataType :</td><td><select name="Name_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" ><option value="text" selected="true" > Text </option><option value="number"  > Number </option><option value="date"  > Date </option></select></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Equals:</td><td> <input type="text" name="Name_equals"/></td></tr> <br/><tr><td>Contains:</td><td> <input type="text" name="Name_contains"/></td></tr><br/>
            </table> 

            <table class="column">
                                    <tr><td>DATE_OF_BIRTH<hr/></td></tr><tr><td>DataType :</td><td><select name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" ><option value="text"  > Text </option><option value="number"  > Number </option><option value="date" selected="true" > Date </option></select></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Equals:</td><td> <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_equals"/></td></tr> <br/><tr><td>Greater_Then:</td><td> <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_greaterThen"/></td></tr><br/><tr><td>Less_Then:</td><td> <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_lessThen"/></td></tr><br/>
            </table> 
            <table class="column">
                                    <tr><td>DATE_OF_BIRTH<hr/></td></tr><tr><td>DataType :</td><td><select name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" ><option value="text"  > Text </option><option value="number"  > Number </option><option value="date" selected="true" > Date </option></select></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Equals:</td><td> <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_equals"/></td></tr> <br/><tr><td>Greater_Then:</td><td> <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_greaterThen"/></td></tr><br/><tr><td>Less_Then:</td><td> <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_lessThen"/></td></tr><br/>
            </table> 

        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why the tables vertical alignment changes from left to right...........

Comment: can you push your code for better understanding

Comment: May be you are talking about http://masonry.desandro.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see a couple of contradictions in what you want to do.

First: You say you want to make the size of the divs fixed, but afterwards you say the divs do not have the same size as they have variable length of text. You must go for one of the two options. If you have variable text in the divs, you must be aware that you cannot make the div's dimensions fixed unless you want to risk the text overflowing the div. That, or check your text to be sure it fits the divs.

Second: You say you are using float: left, but then complain that the element below the last div (the last of the row, I assume) also displays left. If you want the first div of a row to display at the right, you should use float: right.

I hope this clarifies the issue for you.

---

### Update:

Okay, I found the problem with your code. First of all, let me tell you that you shouldn't use tables for layout. `<div>` will make your code simpler and are better for that purpose. Anyway, it wasn't that what was breaking your layout. It was some `<br/>` tags you inserted at the end of the tables for some reason. So your code would look better like this:

```
<form>
<div class="wrapperDiv">
    <table class="column">
        <tr>
            <td>Name<hr/></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType :</td>
            <td>
                <select name="Name_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" >
                    <option value="text" selected="true" > Text </option>
                    <option value="number"  > Number </option>
                    <option value="date"  > Date </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Equals:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name_equals"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contains:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name_contains"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

    <table class="column">
        <tr>
            <td>Name<hr/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType :</td>
            <td>
                <select name="Name_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" >
                    <option value="text" selected="true" > Text </option>
                    <option value="number"  > Number </option>
                    <option value="date"  > Date </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Equals:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name_equals"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contains:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name_contains"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="column">
        <tr>
            <td>Name<hr/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType :</td>
            <td>
                <select name="Name_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" >
                    <option value="text" selected="true" > Text </option>
                    <option value="number"  > Number </option>
                    <option value="date"  > Date </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Equals:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name_equals"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contains:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name_contains"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table class="column">
        <tr>
            <td>DATE_OF_BIRTH<hr/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType :</td>
            <td>
                <select name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" >
                    <option value="text"  > Text </option>
                    <option value="number"  > Number </option>
                    <option value="date" selected="true" > Date </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Equals:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_equals"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Greater_Then:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_greaterThen"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Less_Then:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_lessThen"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

    <table class="column">
        <tr>
            <td>DATE_OF_BIRTH<hr/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType :</td>
            <td>
                <select name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_dataType" class="dataType" onchange="typeChanged(this)" >
                    <option value="text"  > Text </option>
                    <option value="number"  > Number </option>
                    <option value="date" selected="true" > Date </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Equals:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_equals"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Greater_Then:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_greaterThen"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Less_Then:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="DATE_OF_BIRTH_lessThen"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
</form>
```

You can see it working in a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rorok_89/GQkFW/1/).

Comment: The divs have almost same (but not exactly) amount of text and are not greater then certain amount. What i want is that all the divs should have same width and height whatever it is and ,then the sections of my html code to be displayed below the above section not from the side of the section because of some left spaces.

Comment: Ok, so if you want all the divs to have the same width and height all you have to do is set said dimensions in the class you are using for those divs. If you are sure your text will not be more than a certain amount, choose the dimensions that best fit that amount of text and apply that to the divs.

I certainly don't get your second issue about the positioning of those "sections of your code". Can you post an image of what you want to achieve, and some code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Why the square boxes which indicates the table , vertical alignment changes from left to right, is there any way to make the boxes of same top alignment (for those which are in the same row)

Comment: @Rajan, ok, I looked at your code and I think I found the solution. See my updated answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Rorok_89 , I had figured out that if i wrap the tables with div of class .column instead of table itself , it works as well,(just for someone who might watch it). But i have not figured about the <br/> tags , thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome! I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer then (Click the green check symbol) so I can get a bit of rep :)